# How to play video in iPhone without fullscreen mode using WebView in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: iphone, video, xamarin.forms, webview

I am using WebView for playing video in my Xamarin.Forms project. On iPhone the video is playing in fullscreen, but I need to play the video within the WebView without going to fullscreen.

I have this issue only on the iPhone. On Android, Windows, and iPad devices the video is playing without fullscreen.

**Case 1: Normal WebView**

```
<WebView 
    x:Name="web_view"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>

web_view.Source = videoUrl;
```

**Case 2: Custom webview**

On some part, I am using a custom WebView. In this case the video is also being played in full-screen mode.

```
public  class MyWebView : WebView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty UrlProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    propertyName: "Url",
    returnType: typeof(string),
    declaringType: typeof(MyWebView),
    defaultValue: default(string));

    public string Url
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(UrlProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UrlProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

In the above 2 cases, I need to play the video without full-screen mode on the iPhone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set `AllowsInlineMediaPlayback` as True in Custom Renderer

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyWebView), typeof(MyWebViewRenderer))]

namespace CustomWebview.iOS
{
    public class MyWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<MyWebView, WKWebView>
    {
        WKWebView wkWebView;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<MyWebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null)
            {
                WKWebViewConfiguration configuration = new WKWebViewConfiguration();
                configuration.AllowsInlineMediaPlayback = true;
                wkWebView = new WKWebView(CGRect.Empty, configuration);

                if (Element.Url != null)
                {
                    wkWebView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl((Element).Url)));
                }
                SetNativeControl(wkWebView);
            }

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                CallVideo();
            }
        }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.PropertyName.Equals(nameof(Element.Url)))
            {
                wkWebView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl((Element).Url)));
            }
        }

        public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
        {
            base.Draw(rect);

            Control.Frame = rect;
        }
    }
}
```

Added an if statement to exclude the null condition. And then load the URL when you set it in Forms. `OnElementPropertyChanged` will be called when the property of webview has been changed. So when you set its URL in forms, we could load requests in this method.

Comment: Your solution is working for case 2, but for Case 1: Normal WebView, it is not working. I have created a custom renderer for normal webview. But getting null reference exception  in that case.

Comment: It is an expected result. When we init a `WKWebViewConfiguration` , the default property like url will not work any more (it is a new webview) . So why don't you use custom webview instead of normal webview in the whole project ?

Comment: It help me, still have issue in case1. I have created a sample, could you please have a look. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y8oLg2aVoW_Jij4xAYwy4sKZ2gsXFMG5/view?usp=sharing

Comment: As I said , it is impossible to implement it in default WebView .You need to use custom renderer .

Comment: If we set the video url directly, there is no problem. But I need to call a service for getting the video url, in that case the app is breaking with argument null exception.

Comment: I have used the custom renderer in the sample

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215734/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-sreejith-sree).